# How can I make my site to load internal links properly

Tags: navigation, loading

I manage some website and I have this issue.

On this one https://gordian-knot.eu/ when I navigate through the pages, I get this white page in between while the new page loads. What I am trying to find out is if the old page can stay while the new page is loading. Like as in this https://theme-testing.eu/
On the second one the page stays while the new page is loading.

Thank you in advance.
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. My theme had a smooth load effect which was causing this. Disabling it fixed it.
If you have a similar issue check your theme effects.